# Swift4: How to change UITableView cell color

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, background-color

I have a UITable view where you can add items by pressing a button. I want its cells to be clear, I already made its background semitransparent, but once you click on the button that allows you to save the items in it, the first you save has a white background. Then, if you press the button other times, all of the cells, except for the last created, become semitransparent, but one continues to be white. This is my code, how could I make it completely clear?

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return number.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let textCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WordCell", for: indexPath)
        textCell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)         \(number[indexPath.row])"
        let semitransparentBlack = UIColor(rgb: 0x000000).withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        textCell.layer.backgroundColor = semitransparentBlack.cgColor
        textCell.textLabel?.layer.backgroundColor = semitransparentBlack.cgColor
        textCell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        return textCell

    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried `textCell.backgroundColor = semitransparentBlack`?

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I didn't know I could do that without layer, I mean, when I tried other times I got error messages... Thanks it looks great!

Comment: Also if you can try `textCell.contentView.backgroundColor = semitransparentBlack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the color using `textCell.backgroundColor = semitransparentBlack`